# Retry observable queue three times (from the index where it failed)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I got an array of observables. I want to subscribe to each observable source provided only one at a time and not to subscribe to the next until the previous one is finished. If any fails I'd like to retry from the observable that failed (for a couple more times). I don't find a good, smart way to do that.

I'm sure there is more than one way, but I'm not even close to being 'fluent' in rxjs so I'm a bit lost rn. The project I'm working on is using rxjs 6.4.

Cheers and ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `retry(X)` inside `concatMap()` but it really depends on what behavior exactly you want:

```
source$
  .pipe(
    concatMap(val => makeRequest(val).pipe(
      retry(3), // Will retry only this request 3 times.
    )),
  );
```

With `concat`:

```
concat(...sources.map(obs => obs.pipe(retry(3))))
  .subscribe(result => {});
```

Comment: So I want each observable subscribed to in order and if it throws an error I want to retry it two more times. If in any of these retries it works I want it to continue to the next observable if it does not work in any of these 2 tries, I want the whole process to stop and throw an error.

Comment: You can use `concat()` and chain each source with `retry()`. See my update.

Comment: Ty will try it now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RxJS operators `SwitchMap` and `retry`. The `SwitchMaps` chain the observables so that each one waits for the last to emit something.

```
obs1.pipe(
  retry(2)
  switchMap(res1 => obs2.pipe(retry(2)))
  switchMap(res2 => obs3.pipe(retry(2)))
).subscribe(res3 => console.log(res3))
```

EDIT:

What to do if you don't know the amount of observables:

```
let arr = [obs1$, obs2$, obs3$]

of(arr).pipe(
  ...(arr.reduce((p, q) => [...p, switchMap(e), retry(2)]))
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Ty for your answer! Problem with this is I don't know how to do this for an array of unknown length of observables. Is there a solution to that too?

Comment: it edited my post. Can't test it right now though

Comment: Ty for answering Tobias. Will try yours a bit later too. I'm sorry I can't accept both answers. :(